# How do I count numbers of elements that belong to a product_id and save them element-wise in a list in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, list-comprehension, counting

## Create a list that counts the numbers of elements that belong to a product_id e.g. Ikea table

## Given data

```py
product_IDs = [123,123,123,
               321,321,321,
               345,345,345,345,345]
```

## How do I create this list from the product_IDs data?

```py
product_elements = [1, 2, 3, 
                    1, 2, 3,
                    1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

## My Goal

```py
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Product_ID': product_IDs,
        'Product_elements': product_elements
       }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

I tried this and many more things:
[count+1 for count, elle in enumerate(product_IDs)]

Comment: try `df['product_elements'] = df.groupby('product_IDs').cumcount() + 1`

Comment: It works. You are amazing!!! And so fast. Thank you. Such a different approach. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please next time improve formatting in your questions and be more detailed in describing what you've already tried. Have a great day :)

Comment: I will. It's my first time. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> product_IDs = [123,123,123, 321,321,321, 345,345,345,345,345]
>>> product_elements = (pd.Series(product_IDs)
...                     .value_counts(sort=False)
...                     .reset_index()
...                     .apply(
...                         lambda x:list(range(1, x[0]+1) ), 
...                         axis=1
...                     ).explode()
...                     )

>>> pd.DataFrame({
... "product_IDs" : product_IDs,
... "product_elements" : product_elements
... }).reset_index(drop=True)

    product_IDs product_elements
0           123                1
1           123                2
2           123                3
3           321                1
4           321                2
5           321                3
6           345                1
7           345                2
8           345                3
9           345                4
10          345                5
```

Another Solution:

```
>>> x = pd.Series([123,123,123, 321,321,321, 345,345,345,345,345])
>>> (x
...  .groupby(x)
...  .apply(lambda x:range(1, len(x)+1))
...  .explode()
...  .reset_index()
...  .rename(columns={"index" : "product_IDs", 0:"product_elements"})
... )

    product_IDs product_elements
0           123                1
1           123                2
2           123                3
3           321                1
4           321                2
5           321                3
6           345                1
7           345                2
8           345                3
9           345                4
10          345                5
```

Comment: Wow. I knew it is complicated. But I would never come up with such a solution. Smart Amir. Thank you so much. I will try to understand what you did and look up all the functions. Great work!